# Effects of global warming on drought in India

Tags: climate-change, drought

Is there an intuitive explanation for non-specialists why India is projected to experience a decrease in drought (= increase in [PDSI](https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data/palmer-drought-severity-index-pdsi)) due to global warming, unlike most areas at the same latitude(s), at least according to [these maps by 
 Dai (2010)](https://www2.ucar.edu/atmosnews/news/2904/climate-change-drought-may-threaten-much-globe-within-decades)?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it become more wet instead of dryer according to these maps? Or do I miss-understand them?

Comment: @daniel.neumann: India gets wetter... particularly in the long run (bottom maps).

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I miss-understood the title of your question. I though you expected more droughts. Thanks for Clarification.

Comment: The Himalayas may be the most intuitive answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you asked for an intuitive explanation, my thoughts would be that due to predicted increasing sea and global temperatures, the models used might be predicting a corresponding increase in monsoonal moisture or duration.

From [Climate of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_India#Tropical_wet) :

> In India a tropical wet and dry climate is more common. Noticeably
>   drier than areas with a tropical monsoon climate, it prevails over
>   most of inland peninsular India except for a semi arid rain shadow
>   east of the Western Ghats.

An article on 
 the [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/monsoon/) site discusses the relationship between the ocean air temperature and the monsoons in India:

> The summer monsoon is associated with heavy rainfall. It usually
>   happens between April and September. As winter ends, warm, moist air
>   from the southwest Indian Ocean blows toward countries like India, Sri
>   Lanka, Bangladesh, and Myanmar. The summer monsoon brings a humid
>   climate and torrential rainfall to these areas.

So in a region which is warmer, both air and ocean temperature, this monsoon effect is apparently predicted to be altered accordingly, resulting in either a higher precipitation, or longer duration to the wet cycle, to effectively make this region *wetter* than it is today. Without knowing more about how the models were derived, this is just speculation however.